# Update file with some text every second that a windows modal is open

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a windows desktop application which on open of a modal windows form creates a file in the background and writes the creation time in it.
I need to update that file every 5 seconds and compare with creation time so that the modal window is automatically closed after 60 minutes and the file is deleted.
The file creation/deletion and time tracking needs to happen in the background so that the user is not affected by this while working on that modal.

Can this be achieved in a windows desktop application?

Comment: Why a file? why not using a timer?

Comment: why should do that

Comment: Yes it can. Have you tried something so far? because this look like a "write code for me" question.

Comment: This was actually required to track a multi user scenario for a desktop application installed on a shared server. However, the approach changed and we have handled it in code. Thanks for all your replies.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to create a file and update and check it periodically. You can achieve this much easier with timer:

```
var modalForm = new ModalForm();
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0).TotalMilliseconds);
timer.Elapsed += (s, ea) => { modalForm.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(modalForm.Close)); };
modalForm.Shown += (s, ea) => { timer.Start(); };
modalForm.FormClosed += (s, ea) => { timer.Stop(); };
modalForm.ShowDialog();
```

Please note that `Timer.Elapsed` handler is run in a separate thread so you need to employ `Control.Invoke` when calling the modal form's `Close` method. Alternatively, you may set `timer.SynchronizingObject` to `modalForm`:

```
var modalForm = new ModalForm();
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0).TotalMilliseconds);
timer.SynchronizingObject = modalForm;
timer.Elapsed += (s, ea) => { modalForm.Close(); };
modalForm.Shown += (s, ea) => { timer.Start(); };
modalForm.FormClosed += (s, ea) => { timer.Stop(); };
modalForm.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can try a method like the following

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Timer MyTimer = new Timer();
        MyTimer.Interval = (60 * 60 * 1000); // 60 mins
        MyTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(MyTimer_Tick);
        MyTimer.Start();
    }

    private void MyTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The form will now be closed.", "Time Elapsed");
        this.Close();
    }
```